# Simple WCF "Hello world" service occupies only one CPU core under load

Tags: wcf, performance

I have a simple "Hello world" service based on basicHttpBinding. The service is hosted on a quad-core CPU.

When I run load tests only one core is occupied (95%), and the others three approximately 4-8%.

Why are the other cores not used for proccessing?

Setting `ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple` didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Please post client and server code.

Comment: http://zalil.ru/33674140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure a `ServiceBehavior` for your service.

WCF uses `ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single` by default. That mode runs all requests to your service in one thread.

> With ConcurrencyMode.Single, WCF does not call again into the object
>   so long as the method is running. After the operation returns the
>   object can be called again.

One CPU core is used to run that thread.

Add the attribute below for your service to use all the CPUs:

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
```

Be careful with service state when you enable that mode. You may need to implement your own locking if you change state.

Check *[ConcurrencyMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx)* for more details.

Also make sure that your client makes four calls simultaneously (implement multi-threading in client). Without that you still will have sequential one-thread calls processing even if your server supports multi-threading.

**Update after checking the code:**

Your WCF method doesn't do any work that can load the CPU. Please replace your methods with some heavy CPU-using function (calculate hashes or factorial) and re-check.

```
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class HelloService : IHelloService
{
   public string HelloWorld()
   {
      return "Hello world";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [API docs for BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) say this:

> Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

This implies that a single BasicHttpBinding instance should not be called from multiple threads in parallel, and therefore cannot be spread across multiple CPUs/CPU cores.

Comment: Actually what you've quoted is just the standard disclaimer that if you want to use BasicHttpBinding in a multi threaded environment you need to do the locking yourself. The class *by itself* is not thread safe. Opening multiple BasicHttpBinding connections to the same service at the same time works just fine and you can absolutely use multiple CPUs. See Dmitry's answer.